# Handling Touch Events With the BlackBerry Native SDK

Tags: opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, blackberry-10, blackberry-ndk

I'm reading the [OpenGL ES 2.0 Programming Guide](http://opengles-book.com/) and on their examples the use a helper library that they've created called [esUtil.h (which has a version for BlackBerry)](http://code.google.com/p/opengles-book-samples/source/browse/#svn/trunk/BlackBerry/Common/src), that is contained on the [book examples repository](http://code.google.com/p/opengles-book-samples/), the problem is that now I want to [handle touch events](https://developer.blackberry.com/native/documentation/recipe_touch_1935310_11.html), but I don't know how to make my code compactible with the `bbutil.h` initialization so I can take advantage of the touch and at the same time have `esUtil.h` so I can take advantage of functions like `esRegisterDrawFunc`, `esRegisterUpdateFunc` and `esMainLoop`, which I don't know how to do with `bbutil`. Here's my code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "esUtil/esUtil.h"

// BlackBerry stuff.
#include "bbutil.h"
#include <bps/bps.h>
#include <bps/screen.h>

// Helpers.
#include "helpers/global.h"
#include "helpers/shaders.h"

// Scene.
#include "scene/scene.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    ESContext esContext;
    UserData userData;

    esInitContext(&esContext);
    esContext.userData = &userData;

    if (!esCreateWindow(&esContext, TITLE, WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT, ES_WINDOW_RGB))
        return 0;

    if (!init(&esContext))
        return 0;

    esRegisterDrawFunc(&esContext, drawScene);
    esRegisterUpdateFunc(&esContext, update);

    esMainLoop(&esContext);

    return 0;
}
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I don't have any specific experience mixing OpenGL with BPS, but since there hasn't been any other response...

I have mixed BPS with Cascades under BB10. What I did was run the BPS event fetching and response code on a separate thread. The thread will block until BPS has an event. This leaves the main thread available for Cascades (in my case) or esMainLoop (in your case).